# why the array index is undefined?

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I am using Yii, and I want to print an index of an array, but I get an error that the index is undefined, here is my code:

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
 $criteria->select = 'username, password'; // select fields which you want in output
 $u = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);

 foreach($u as $u)
        $users["$u->username"] = "$u->password";

echo $users['a'];
```

I printed the array and make sure that `a` index is exist, so what is the problem here?

Comment: `var_dump` your array and see what indexes are there. Also `($u as $u)` is BAAAD idea.

Comment: nothing to solve here, the index `a` was stored in the the db with w space so it is ` a`, I think I need to visit the ophthalmologist.

Comment: i would clean up the db and input functions then, but you can use `trim()` to just clean it up here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) you must first specify the array you want to iterate over (`$u` in this case) and and a different variable after "as" to indicate the variable it should be known as within the scope of the `foreach()` loop. You must also declare `$users` to be an array so that you can add items to it. You do not need double quotes when using it is an index or array value.

```
// create $users array to store values
$users = array();
// iterate over the $u array referring to elements as $user
foreach ( $u as $user ){
    // place properties of $user into the $users array
    $users[$user->username] = $user->password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'username, password'; 
$u = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);

foreach($u as $val){
    $users["$val->username"] = "$val->password";
}
print_r($users);
```

Comment: You think that db query returns field value as an index?

Comment: Please provide a description of your answer and not just code.